# Can't reference an Android library into my project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, libraries

I would like to use the android project [PagerSliding](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

I have imported it into my workspace.
After that I get into MY project properties add a library, and then click apply and ok, so I get :

[image: Step 1]

If I reopen MY project properties right after here's what I get (Eclipse seems to loose the reference to the library).

[image: Step 2]

FYI : I did have 2 workspaces before, but now I'm using only one.

Comment: check the project.properties file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628449/google-play-services-lib-jar-missing-after-updating-to-latest-version-3-1/16628804#16628804. Check the answer in the link. Might help. I am not sure though. Did this happen after updating sdk and adt?

Comment: @Raghunandan : no, simple installing, no updating or whatsoever..

Comment: @blackbelt : project.properties seems fine

Comment: eclipse uses that file for libraries references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved to issue by removing eclipse, and reinstalling, seems to be a Eclipse bug when previously using 2 workspaces...

According to this question [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709859/eclipse-android-project-losing-reference-to-library-project-viewpagerindicator)

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the project and importing it again worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem there when i try to change my workspace so this my solution:

```
1. import and copy all project data including library project into workspace
2. delete the old project reference by Right-click on the project-->Properties-->Android-->Library, and select corrupted library(so that waht i call it) and choose Remove
3. clean project first (to refresh ur project properties)
4. go to library project Properties-->Android-->Library and check the is library if it does'nt click Apply then OK
5. if the library project is library is already checked, first Unchecked it then Clean the library project after that do the Step 4 again
6. go to project that u want the library are in then Right-click on the project-->Properties-->Android-->Library, Add then choose the library project (it should be there) and click Apply then OK
7. if still doesn't appear clean the project once more time and that should do
```

thanks